# AngularJS controllers: Move common code to separate file

Tags: angularjs

I have some controllers with some common code, specifically a `$scope.$watch` that is identical for several controllers. How can I put this code in a separate file and import the common code in the various controllers that needs this `$watch`?

Comment: could service work for this?

Comment: I am pretty sure scope in a service is not possible...

Comment: @EricC $scope would just be a parameter for a service function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **could** use a service by passing in your controller's scope:

```
angular.module('app').service("CommonFunctions", ['SomeService', function(SomeService) {
    var commonFunctions = {};
    commonFunctions.init = function(scope){
        scope.$watch(function(){},function(){})
    };
    return commonFunctions;
}]);

angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl1', 
['$scope','CommonFunctions',function($scope,CommonFunctions) {
    CommonFunctions.init($scope);
}]);

angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl2', 
['$scope','CommonFunctions',function($scope,CommonFunctions) {
    CommonFunctions.init($scope);
}]);
```

This way you're using the individual controller's scope, but using a common method within a service.  You could also use `angular.extend($scope, AService)` within a controller if you want common functionality from a service actually added to controller scopes.

Here's a working **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/rhcjdb7L/

Sure that's very cool and all, but are you sure you don't want to use `$rootscope.$broadcast()`?  This is pretty well written: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: I don't see the point of extending $scope. You already have a service. Just call `CommonFunctions.init($scope)`

Comment: You're right, `extend()` is overkill in this case since you don't need that function in $scope for any reason.  I've revised my answer.